# Magento sales report query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, phpmyadmin

i am using magento 1.4.2
I am trying to bulid custom sales report but does't find model to find sales report query.
***plz help***

Comment: What do you mean by sales report? The grid/table that we see in Admin panel for all sales?

Comment: Reports->sales->order (i want query of this report)

Comment: The SQL query is built by the system as it is needed according to the filters you choose. It is not written in one place. If you want to customise a report then you should be trying to extend the class of one with your own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following links for more insight into creating a Custom Sales Report:-

- [Magento Forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/29535/)
- [Magento Coder - Create Custom Reports in Magento Admin](http://magentocoder.jigneshpatel.co.in/create-custom-reports-in-magento-admin/)

As far as to what I've seen is that it is better to look into the controller of the "`Adminhtml_Report`" module, instead of the Model file, because in the controller class, most of the logic is written.

Please check this class "`Mage_Adminhtml_Report_SalesController`" for more info on creating the Custom Sales Report in Admin.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want query of sales report to fetch data

Comment: For each section of Magento Admin, there is no method / class, where you will be able to find a proper query specifically, mentioning the "`SELECT`" keyword. However, if you look carefully for the "`_prepareCollection()`" method in the leaf class of the module's "`Block`" section, you will be able to find query related methods being used to prepare / build the collection.         And the main thing is you need to follow the coding of Magento "`Adminhtml`" module's different sections to know & write more of such custom requirements.